# Install script version logic: When are which upgrade scripts executed?

Tags: install-script, upgrade-script, versioning

I found an interesting behavior today: I accidently named a data upgrade script `data-upgrade-0.1.20-0.1.20.php` where it should have been `data-upgrade-0.1.19-0.1.20.php`, and it actually has been applied.

And as I cannot find a question here that can be used as a reference for the setup script version logic (correct me if I'm wrong), let's use this one.

**By which logic does Magento execute the install and upgrade scripts?**

Especially interesting edge case: When and why are scripts like `upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.0.php` executed, where the "from" version number is equal to the "to" version number?

Comment: wow thats weird. Data upgrades are only executed if the `version_compare` returns 1. Equal should return 0.

Comment: That's what I would expect. But the current version *was* 0.1.19, so it makes sense that the `version_compare` check returned 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method that calls the upgrades (at least one in the chain) is this in `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup`

```
public function applyDataUpdates()
{
    $dataVer= $this->_getResource()->getDataVersion($this->_resourceName);
    $configVer = (string)$this->_moduleConfig->version;
    if ($dataVer !== false) {
         $status = version_compare($configVer, $dataVer);
         if ($status == self::VERSION_COMPARE_GREATER) {
             $this->_upgradeData($dataVer, $configVer);
         }
    } elseif ($configVer) {
        $this->_installData($configVer);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Your module had the version (`$configVer`) `0.1.19`, so magento reads all the available scripts in the sql folder and the file `0.1.20-0.1.20` matched the condition `if ($status == self::VERSION_COMPARE_GREATER) {` because the `$configVer` variable is not incremented after each script executes.
So it always compares to `0.1.19` until the upgrade finishes.

<sub>Side note: this is a crazy one indeed.</sub>

Comment: nice one! But yeah, kinda weird it doesn't update the `from` during upgrade